# Controlling Modals with States and Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, frontend, reactstrap

I am trying to use Reactstrap to create modals that pop up when navigated through the nav bar.

My strategy is to change the state in the parent component and pass them as props to the `isOpen` attribute to control opening the modals.

The problem is changing the props in the child component doesn't re-render components so I am not able to close the modals!

Parent Controller:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      zipcode : '',
      zipEntered: false
      };
    this.onZipCodeChange = this.onZipCodeChange.bind(this);
    this.isAuth = this.isAuth.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({signup:false});
    if(this.state.zipcode !== '' || this.state.zipcode !== undefined){
      this.setState({zipEntered:true});
      this.setState({zipcode:this.state.zipcode});
    } else {
      this.setState({zipcode: '' });
      this.setState({zipEntered:false});
    }
  }

  onZipCodeChange(zip){
    //console.log('App has detected ZipCode Change: '+zip);
    this.setState({zipcode: zip});
    this.setState({zipEntered:false});
  }

  isAuth(token){
    console.log("App has token: "+ token);
    //pull data from token
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">InkSpace</a>
              <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => {this.setState({zipEntered:true})}}>Change Zipcode</a>
                </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => {this.setState({signup:true})}}>Tattooist</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">Shop</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </header>
          <ZipCode onSubmit={this.onZipCodeChange} isOpen={this.state.zipEntered} />
          <GMap zipcode={this.state.zipcode} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child Controller:

```
class ZipCode extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        zipcode:''          };
      this.submitZipCode = this.submitZipCode.bind(this);
      this.zipcodeChange = this.zipcodeChange.bind(this);
    }

  submitZipCode(e){
  //  console.log('submitting zipcode');
    e.preventDefault();
    const { onSubmit } = this.props; //pull out to call method it is linked to
    onSubmit(this.state.zipcode);
    this.setState({isOpen:false});
  }

  zipcodeChange(e){
    this.setState({zipcode: e.target.value});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>ZipCode</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
           <form  onSubmit={this.submitZipCode}>
               <label>Zip Code</label>
               <input
                 type="input"
                 name="zipcode"
                 value={this.state.zipcode}
                 onChange={this.zipcodeChange}
                />
              <Button color="primary" type="submit" className='btn btn-success'>Submit</Button>
            </form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default ZipCode;
```

Comment: there is no `this.toggle` in child.

Comment: don't do `this.setState({zipcode: zip}); this.setState({zipEntered:false});` do `this.setState({zipcode: zip, zipEntered:false});`

Comment: @BardiaRastin I tried using states. It wouldn't work. I'll def condense them however. Are you stating I'm basically re-rendering twice?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk Maybe related to my `this.toggle` problem? but even without that in props it works.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St yes, exactly, it's an anti patern

Comment: @BardiaRastin am I going to have to set all the states in every place I call `this.setState()`? Or do you mean do that in a specific line in my code?